# iPhone keyboard goes away when UIImagePicker comes up

Tags: ios

Apple's FoodTracker tutorial for writing iOS apps using Xcode and Swift involves a text field and an image picker. The user can enter text into the text field and have the app display that text in a label. Separately, when the app's user clicks on an image that the app displays, an image picker is created to let the user select a different image and have the app display that image.

According to the tutorial, the function that gets called when the user taps on the image needs to call the text field's resignFirstResponder function in order to get rid of the keyboard that is displayed while the text field is being used, but I'm finding that this isn't the case. I can comment out that call to resignFirstResponder, and the keyboard still goes away. Furthermore, if I start using the text field in the app but then tap the image to bring up the image picker, the text field's textFieldDidEndEditing function gets called regardless of whether the image picker's code calls resignFirstResponder on the text field.

Can someone please shed some light on this situation? Personally, I think it makes sense that the image picker code doesn't have to worry about the text field, but Apple's tutorial claims otherwise. Here's a link to the part of the tutorial that claims a call to resignFirstResponder is necessary. You'll see it quickly if you just search for "resignFirstResponder." https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. By presenting the new viewcontroller the textfield is no longer in front so it can't be the first responder anymore. But the problem is that it is not that sure that it works then calling .resignFirstResponer. So it is more to make sure that it will work.